# How to rotate android spinner dropdown window

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve a vertical `Spinner`. I am able to rotate the spinner view using

```
 spinner.setRotation(-90);
```

But this rotates only spinner view but not the dropdown list. As shown in the below image.
How to rotate dropdown window also?

[image]

After trying below answer I am getting into this problem

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `spinner.getParent().setRotation(-90);`?

Comment: @PedroOliveira getParent does not have setRotaion method

Comment: Nvm it will not work this way.

Comment: Do you have a custom adapter?

Comment: No. I have normal array adapter.. I am fine to shift to custom adapter if you have solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a custom adapter for your spinner.

Next on your getView make sure you rotate the parent that get's passed to it.

An example adapter:

```
public class AdapterTest extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


    public AdapterTest(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_spinner, parent, false);
        if (parent.getRotation() == 0 && parent instanceof ListView) {
             parent.setRotation(-90);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can you please let me know the usage

Comment: What usage? This is a custom adapter. You just have to create an instance of the custom adapter and set it to your spinner. Simple.

Comment: @user3270537 So where you able to implement this?

Comment: I could implement it but there is a problem. Its clipping off first and last row of the dropdown menu

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and show us how that looks?

Comment: Did not help.. same result